# Magento images not showing in backend

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I have a serious problem with my Magento 1.8.1 installation. It is not possible to view or upload any images in backend. The images once uploaded show up fine in frontend, but in the backend: nothing. Even the upload buttons are missing.

I already tried to

- set the the right permissions (777) on /media
- updated my flash on all my browsers
- replaced the corresponding .swf files

Is there anything I can do? Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you open the product page in admin, have check consol or log file of magento.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

Enable Adobe Flash Player for use in the web browser.

https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enabling-flash-player-chrome.html